# How to Retrieve list of attributes from multiple Firebase nodes

Tags: android, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, endpoint

My firebase DB looks like

[image]

Now I want to query the database such that I take all the users whose email id is in a query list.

For example in the above shown database structure, if I want to make a query such that find the users where username in ["allen20252482", "arne19712450"] which can give me two users.

Is it possible?

Currently I can query like `https://xyz.firebaseio.com/users.json` to get the complete user node data , But is it possible to filter like where I take only those users whose username is in the given query list?

I am using REST API endpoint to query the Firebase DB.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the documentation on [filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering).  It sounds like you want to filter by a child key:

```
https://xyz.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="username"&equalTo="abcdef"
```

You will only be able to specify one username at a time.

Comment: yes I know that I can do that query , but my question is if it is possible to query with list as params

Comment: for example I need users whose username belongs to a list ["u1", "u2", "u2"]
so its not possible?

Comment: As I said in my answer: "You will only be able to specify one username at a time"